# Let $V$ be the vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ of sequences with rational values. Find an infinite, linearly independent subset of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was given the following problem:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ of sequences with rational values; *id est*, functions $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$. Find an infinite subset of $V$ that is linearly independent.

I'm having trouble understanding what is being required. $V$ is a set of functions $f: \mathbb{N} 
 \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, so the problem seems to be asking is for an infinite set of functions $f: \mathbb{N} 
 \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ such that $q_1f_1 +q_2f_2 +... q_nf_n \neq 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ for any non-null sequence $Q = \{q_1, q_2,... \}$ of rational numbers. In other words, it seems I should find some sequences of $f$s and $q$s such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty q_if_i \neq 0$$

However, I feel this way of formulating the problem is not very helpful. I'm not looking for solutions to the problem (yet, anyway), but rather to find the correct representation of what is being asked so as to worked from there. I'm very new to linear algebra. Thanks!

Comment: Linear Independence means that no *finite* sum of terms is $\vec 0$ unless all the coefficients are $0$.  There is no general notion of infinite sums in a vector space.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^\infty q_if_i$ is different from $ q_1f_1 +q_2f_2 +... q_nf_n $